# Read simple XML file using python

Tags: python, xml

I'm trying to get publish date from XML file. please see my xml file.

```
<sdnList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/sdnList.xsd">
  <publshInformation>
    <Publish_Date>06/10/2021</Publish_Date>
    <Record_Count>8954</Record_Count>
  </publshInformation>
</sdnList>
```

I'm trying below way but its not working and I don't want to use for loop for simple file. Thanks

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("test.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

publish_Date = root.findall("Publish_Date")

for pdate in publish_Date:
   print(pdate.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the namespace.
see below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<sdnList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/sdnList.xsd">
 <publshInformation>
   <Publish_Date>06/10/2021</Publish_Date>
   <Record_Count>8954</Record_Count>
 </publshInformation>
</sdnList>'''


root = ET.fromstring(xml)
print(root.find('.//{http://tempuri.org/sdnList.xsd}Publish_Date').text)
```

output

```
06/10/2021
```